# MDX AllMembers doesn't show calculated members

Tags: mdx

Say I have as hierarchy `[Rank].[Rank]` with three members

```
[Rank].[Rank].&[Boss]
[Rank].[Rank].&[Manager]
[Rank].[Rank].&[Supervisor]
[Rank].[Rank].&[Serf]
```

Then create a calcuated member in the query

```
MEMBER [Rank].[Rank].[Middle Managers] AS 
      [Rank].[Rank].&[Manager] + [Rank].[Rank].&[Supervisor]
```

if I say

```
with 

member [Rank].[Rank].[Middle Managers] AS 
           [Rank].[Rank].&[Manager] + [Rank].[Rank].&[Supervisor]

select
   {
     [Measures].[Hours] 
   }
   on 0

   , [Rank].[Rank].[Rank].ALLMEMBERS
   on 1
from 
  some_cube
```

I don't get the [Rank].[Rank].[Middle Managers] appearing in resultset, but if I use

```
with 

member [Rank].[Rank].[Middle Managers] AS 
           [Rank].[Rank].&[Manager] + [Rank].[Rank].&[Supervisor]

select
   {
     [Measures].[Hours On Stack Overflow] 
   }
   on 0

   , [Rank].[Rank].[Rank].ALLMEMBERS + [Rank].[Rank].[Middle Managers]
   on 1
from 
  some_cube
```

I do get it.

But I was under the impression that ALLMEMBERS includes calculated members. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming is a bit confusing ([Rank].[Rank].[Rank] vs [Rank].[Rank] usage); you might try (notice the extra [Rank] in the name):

```
with member [Rank].[Rank].[Rank].[Middle Managers] AS 
           [Rank].[Rank].&[Manager] + [Rank].[Rank].&[Supervisor]
```

[edit] is attaching your calc. member into a member that is the level above [Rank] working:

```
with member [Rank].[Rank].&[Boss].parent.[Middle Managers] AS 
           [Rank].[Rank].&[Manager] + [Rank].[Rank].&[Supervisor]
```

Comment: So you're saying I need to define the calculated member on the level and not on the hierarchy? If so I get this `Query (3, 1) The '[Rank]' member was not found in the cube when the string, [Rank].[Rank].[Rank].[Middle Managers], was parsed.` It appears the calculated members need to be defined on the hierarchy.

Comment: Then [Rank].[Rank].[Rank].ALLMEMBERS is right; it gives you all the members in the [Rank] * level * ; your calc. member has not been created in this level.

Comment: To an extent you're right - thanks for all your help. I just tested [Rank].[Rank].ALLMEMBERS and yes it does have the members, unfortunetly it also has [Rank].[Rank].[All] but that's ok I can eliminate that (and the others I wanted to eliminate) with a calculated SET! Thanks again!